# Push Notifications for an app developed using sencha touch 2

Tags: android, push-notification, sencha-touch-2, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

How push notifications be implemented for a sencha touch 2 application? I need the device id to be send to a php server as the first step. I have not proceeded much far in this. I just created a slider for enabling/disabling push notifications

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SettingsPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'settingspanel',
    id:'settingspanel',
    backButton : {
        visible : true,
        ui : 'blue_back_button'
    },
    config: {

            items:[

                   {
                       xtype:'togglefield',
                       name: 'pushnotifications',
                       value: 1,
                       label: 'Enable Push Notifications?',
                       labelWidth: '40%',
                       height:'100%'
                   } 
                   ]
        },


});
```

So when I enable the above slider, I need to send the device id to a server . I need help for android and ios devices

Comment: If you are using javascript then you can probably have a look at Websocket and Server sent events API from HTML 5 Documentation

Comment: @LalithB can you send the urls for those documentations?Also I need to get device ID

Comment: Also if you are trying to deploy you app specific to android then the server sent events will probably wont work with native android browsers, it works with Android Chrome and Firefox Mobile. More details here - http://caniuse.com/eventsource Documentations are available here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/EventSource
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://blog.pubnub.com/building-a-pubnub-powered-chat-app-with-sencha-touch-2/

I have used this to make push notifications in my app, and it works like charm.